# ASP.NET Core How to set variables for Dev, Staging and Production environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

This is my current project structure

1. CentralRepo (Stores multiple appsettings.json files)
2. AppOne (AppOne references CentralRepo in order to read the appsettings.json file)

Example (Program.cs):

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(ConfigurationManager.GetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CENTRAL_REPO")))
.AddJsonFile("apponesettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.Build();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
    var connectionString = Configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:ConnectionString"];
    LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = connectionString;
    try
    {
        logger.Debug("init main");
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //NLog: catch setup errors
        logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
        NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

I am currently using an Environment Variable in order to set my CENTRAL_REPO path. However, I realized that when I deploy this to my development server, I can only have one environment variable with that name. How can I change this so that I can have one for development, staging and production?

Is there another way to do this rather than use environment variables?

I read about web.config files but I am unsure of how to set a variable within it and then call it from my code.

Comment: To use of the web.config, you just have to create a Web.Dev.config, Web.Prod.config etc
Their content will be the same, in the Web.config you'll put all the settings that won't change and in the Dev.config and Prod.config, you'll have the same set of variables in the appsettings that will have different values. 
All you have to do in your code is to use "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingName"]". No need to specify the environnement, it's detected with the build, it generates the right Web.config depending on the environnement.
Sorry for my lousy english.

Comment: It's literally a case of right-click web.config -> Add transforms and then you get a web.config for each of the configurations you've defined in Visual Studio. Simple, easy, no messing around with environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variable in web.config [with this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#setting-environment-variables) like this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
      arguments=".\MyApp.dll"
      stdoutLogEnabled="false"
      stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"
      hostingModel="InProcess">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    <environmentVariable name="CONFIG_DIR" value="f:\application_config" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Comment: There is no `web.config` in ASP.NET Core anymore. Now it's `appsettings.json`

Answer (score 4):

You can set environment variables for each environment at different json file like below ;

[image]

and get the variables at Startup.cs like below :

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }
```

Comment: Can't see where you set the env variables?

Comment: @Legends variables are inside of appsettings.json files. Defining variables in json files is similar with oder json definitions , typical key - value structure. Idea here is you call diffrent json files for each environment.

Comment: That's my question, how does asp.net know which environment we are currently in and therefore which `appsettings.{env}.json` to load?
Where do you set .i.e `Test/Staging/Production` --> `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable

Comment: Ok, I see there is a myriad of ways doing it, thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables can also be set in the `profiles` section of `launchSettings.json`. Look for `environmentVariables` and then `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.

Note there can be more than one instance. I'm never sure which profile to change so I always change them all:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:4953/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Registrations/FindByCode?code=1234",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    },
    "My.WebService20": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Registrations/FindByCode?code=1234",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:4954/"
    }
  }
}
```