# my azure web app doesn't read parameter from correct appsetting.{env}.json file

Tags: azure, .net-core, appsettings, azure-webapps

I developed an azure web app (dotnetcore 3.1) and added appsettings files for each environment like

- appsettings.json
- appsettings.Prod.json
- appsettings.Staging.json
- appsettings.Development.json

it was working in my local as expected but when I deploy it to the Azure portal, it always reads the parameter from the appsettings.json file even though I add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Staging to the azure application settings. I am expecting it should read parameters from appsettings.Staging.json file in this case.

what could I miss? Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance...

**MVC Web app**

[image]

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
        IConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        
        IConfiguration cfg = cb.Build();

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddSingleton(cfg);
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var key = _configuration["Settings:firstKey"].ToString();
    ViewBag.FirstKey = key;
    return View();
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Settings": {
    "firstKey": "from appsettings.json"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Staging.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Settings": {
    "firstKey": "from appsettings.Staging.json"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Settings": {
    "firstKey": "from appsettings.Development.json"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Prod.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Settings": {
    "firstKey": "from appsettings.Prod.json"
  }
}
```

**azure application settings**
[image]

Comment: I thought it could be case sensitive, therefore I changed staging to Staging in Azure application settings, but nothing changed.

Comment: Please refer [Warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#setting-environment-variables)

Comment: Environment variables can also be set in the profiles section of launchSettings.json. Look for environmentVariables and then ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.Refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043460/16630207)

Comment: Also refer [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT, the launchSettings.json file shows only localhost settings, I don't think it causes the issue...

Comment: my production and staging environment is already different, the application is running on a different app service plan that is for staging. so even though I set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development or Staging or whatever, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by updating program.cs and startup.cs files like the ones below.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // removed appsettings configuration in startup.cs file
   services.AddMemoryCache();
   services.AddSession();
   services.AddMvc();
   services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
       webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
       .ConfigureAppConfiguration((config)=> {
         var appSetting = $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)}.json";
         config.AddJsonFile(appSetting, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
       });
    });
```

I guess the web app isn't able to read environment variables in the startup.cs at first, when it is deployed to Azure portal

result

[image]